# Excel VBA: saving autofilter settings, with exact values

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I want to run a procedure which saves autofilter settings, does stuff, potentially edits the filter and then reapplies it.

I am using the following code to save the autofilter data:

```
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter
    Set filtRange = .Range

    With .Filters
        fieldNumber = .Count
        ReDim filtArray(1 To fieldNumber, 1 To 4)

        For f = 1 To fieldNumber
            With .Item(f)
                If .On Then
                    filtArray(f, 1) = 1
                    filtArray(f, 2) = .Operator
                    filtArray(f, 3) = Criteria1
                    If .Operator <= 2 And .Operator > 0 Then
                        filtArray(f, 4) = Criteria2
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next f

    End With

End With
```

My issue is that the criteria are not saved as they would be for input. e.g. a top 10 filter you would input 10 into the `Criteria1` field and use the `xlTop10items` operator. But using this method returns `Criteria1` as, e.g. `>=50`, if 50 is the tenth highest value.

I could implement a long procedure that works back from this, works out what rank 50 is and then deduces that this is a top 10 filter (rather than, say, a top 5), since I know that it is a top X filter from the operator, but is there a better way of getting this info?

The reason I need this information is that I want to reapply the filter with as little loss of info as possible, i.e. a user shouldn't notice that it has changed. I may also require, say, changing a top 10 filter to a top (10 - X) filter etc etc.

I've used top 10 filters as an example but there is a similar issue with  above/below average - returns `>=X`/`<=Y`.

Additionally it doesn't work for icon filtering at all, but I don't think this is a major issue for me as very unlikely to encounter it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to rethink.

"I want to run a procedure which saves autofilter settings, does stuff, potentially edits the filter and then reapplies it."

I think you might be able to change how you are thinking  this problem through eg

I have a table with an autofilter applied.
I want to end up with a table that has the same autofitler applied, but that may have some filters added or removed.

I need to do stuff  to the table to determine what filters need to be added and removed.
I may delete or add rows to the table (which I can do without removing the filters).

I may even take a copy of the whole sheet and remove the filter only from the copy so that I can view and work out the STUFF to be done...

If I leave the filter in place it gets around some of the problems I might face.
(I can still work with the underlying range of data in VBA)

ALSO NOTE:

Using the local window I set up a filter of top ten items which in the locals windows gave me criteria1 = ">=10"
I edited the data.
I then used ribbon?Data>Sort&Filter>REAPPLY
in the locals window it now  gave me criteria1 = ">=5"

So, I think REAPPLY will be key to you.

Harvey

Answer (score 0):

I done something similar before. By using below calculation to identify the Top/Bottom Ranking.

But It's not 100% accurate, (means it will return the exactly same records, provided the data are remain the same)

therefore, before saving the Autofilter setting, will prompt a input box.
Let user key in the correct Ranking.

```
 'isTopBottomFilter is UDF function

 If isTopBottomFilter(iFilter) Then
        nRank = CInt(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(nRange, Filter.Criteria1))

        If Filter.Operator = xlTop10Percent Or Filter.Operator = xlBottom10Percent Then
            nRank = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((nRank * 100) / Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(nRange), 0)
        End If
 End if
```

Hope this help !